# Is Joseph Curwen a Lich?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, undead, the-case-of-charles-dexter-ward

In H. P. Lovecraft's *The Case of Charles Dexter Ward*, is Joseph Curwen a lich, [as defined by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich)?

Comment: What do you mean by "lich"? It's not a real category of being, so the definition is completely dependent on the fictional setting.

Comment: @sumelic by "lich" I mean exactly the wikipedia definition provided at joshbirk answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Technically he could be called one**

Defining [Lich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich) as:

> In fantasy fiction, a lich (/ˈlɪtʃ/;[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich) sometimes spelled liche, cognate to Dutch lijk and German Leiche, both meaning "corpse") is a type of undead creature. Often such a creature is the result of a transformation, as a powerful magician or king striving for eternal life uses spells or rituals to bind his intellect to his animated corpse and thereby achieve a form of immortality.

And from the [text](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/cdw.aspx):

> His older aspect increased to a startling degree his resemblance to the Curwen portrait in his library; and Dr. Willett would often pause by the latter after a call, marvelling at the virtual identity, and reflecting that only the small pit above the picture’s right eye now remained to differentiate ***the long-dead wizard from the living youth***.

Emphasis mine.  The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Case_of_Charles_Dexter_Ward) even refers to him as an "undead sorceror":

> Armed with this knowledge, Willett confronts Curwen at the asylum and succeeds in reversing the spell, reducing ***the undead sorcerer*** once again to dust, the dust that was mentioned at the start of the story.

So given the elements of death, sorcery and immortality - I don't see why not.

Answer (score 6):

The only actual use of the word "lich" in the literature associated with Lovecraft is in August Derleth's (under a pseudonym) "The Extra Passenger."  The usage there indicated a reanimated corpse, more intelligent than a zombie, but a corpse all the same.  Derleth indicated the supernatural appearance of the corpse to the activity of a demon transporting it there, so it would more or less be an undead body that the intelligence and personality had not left.

Comment: Clark Ashton Smith used the word "lich" frequently—in "The Abominations of Yondo," for example

Answer (score 1):

Joseph Curwen's technique was to reduce living things to a "bluish-grey dust", and later resuscitate them. From how I understand it, this second part is simply a reversal of the first, so the subject is just as "alive" after as they were before. Curwen did not actually die in the fire, but performed the spell on himself while it was raging, so as to trick everyone into thinking he was dead. Of course, this does not quite explain what he intended to do with Ben Franklin's corpse, but that whole plot-line was pretty vague and confusing anyway.
A lich, as defined in Dungeons and Dragons, is an intelligent animated corpse with spellcasting capabilities and fear factor. A lich is naturally and obviously in a state of decomposition and is thus frightening to look at. Joseph Curwen, on the other hand, was nearly indistinguishable from his descendent Charles Dexter Ward. I am sure Ward's parents would have noticed had their son suddenly become a revenant. True, Lovecraft described Curwen as "undead", but he also once described penguins as "grotesque". So what does he know?
In the words of Pushing Daisies: Curwen is not undead, he is alive again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is a bit complicated, but it appears that you're saying "no" because Curwen is alive, so he can't be a lich.  How does that fit with the quoted passage about his being a "long-dead wizard" and him being "undead?"